# Tkinter scrollbar scrolling infinitely down but breaks when scrolling up

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Hi I can't seem to find the cause of a weird issue I am having in Tkinter\Python

When using the following code to create a scrolling window on a canvas

```
myFrame = Frame(ob)
ob.create_window((0, 0), window=myFrame, anchor='nw')
scroll = Scrollbar(sub, orient="vertical", command=ob.yview)
ob.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.grid(row=0, column=1,  sticky=N+S)
# add check boxes for clients to buttons
for row in clients:
    v = IntVar()
    item = Checkbutton(myFrame, text=row[1], variable=v)
    item.va = v
    item.grid(sticky='w')
    clientlist[str(row[0])] = v
ob.configure(scrollregion=ob.bbox('all'))
```

It creates the windows inside of the canvas and also creates the items inside of it. It even creates the scrollbar next to the canvas just fine.

The issue is that when I scroll down it allows me to scroll forever. It also scrolls upwards just past the top most item in the canvas window and then disables the scroll function.

Any insight on this as it seems I must not be setting the scroll region correctly is my guess but I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: Could you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and indicate what system you are running?

Comment: Do you literally mean "scroll forever"? That is, if you drag the scrollbar thumb all the way to the bottom, what happens?

Comment: Just a guess, but you may need to call `update_idletasks()` (to give your frame a chance to calculate what its dimensions are) before `bbox()` will give you valid results.

Comment: @BryanOakley the thumb no, but the down button yes. If I drab the thumb down to the bottom it doesn't scroll the right distance. It's starting full sized but shrinks if I scroll down

Comment: @jasonharper you were right. None of the docs I was looking at had that mentioned but simply adding that call before setting the scroll region fixed it.

Comment: It's pretty common to create a binding to the `<Configure>` event of the inner frame, and reset the `scrollregion` in the bound function. That way the scroll region will be updated automatically whenever the interior widget changes size (which it does when you add widgets to it and the window is mapped to the screen)